# Ember-data: How DS.attr("number") is supposed to work?

Tags: javascript, php, ember.js, ember-data

I'm using DS.RESTAdapter, php on server. I have a model UacList:

```
DS.Model.extend({
    dummyFieldForErrors: DS.attr("string"),
    selected: DS.attr("number"),
    uacs: DS.hasMany("uac")
});
```

Ember sends request GET /rest/uacLists/1. Server response is:

```
{
    "uacList":{
        "id":1,
        "selected":32483,
        "uacs":[33618,9678,...,33656]
    },
    "uacs": [...]
}
```

But Ember Inspector tells me that selected is undefined (other attributes have values they should have according to server response). No matter if there is a quotes ("selected":"32483") or not ("selected":32483), it is undefined anyway. If I define this attribute as a string, it works but I don't like when an integer is defined as a string.

Comment: Does the Ember Inspector tell you that the values is `undefined` or `null`?

Comment: @gjk undefined. Ember inspector tells me, that `{id: 1, dummyFieldsForErrors: undefined, selected: undefined, uacs: <DS.ManyArray:ember548>}`. But **selected** should be 32483 or other number, returned in server's answer.

Comment: You say that it works if you change it to a string? Judging by the fact that `dummyFieldsForErrors` is also `undefined`, and you have two `uacs` properties in your JSON, it seems like you just have your response JSON formatted incorrectly.

Comment: @GJK dummyFieldForErrors should be undefined. When server returns errors, it should send them in following format: `{"errors":{"attributeName":[/*array of strings*/]}}`, and "attributeName" should be one of attributes, defined in model. That's why I added dummyFieldForErrors to send some general errors from server (if user unauthorized, etc). JSON is formatted according to documentation: http://emberjs.com/guides/models/the-rest-adapter/#toc_sideloaded-relationships.

Comment: There's nothing that I can see here that would cause your issues. Can you create a JSBin that reproduces the issue?

Comment: @GJK I'm afraid not, too much code needed to reproduce this. I hope someone ran into such issue and may explain. For now I'll left this attribute defined as string `selected: DS.attr("string")`

Comment: Does the `uacs:  <DS.ManyArray:ember548>` actually contain values? I'm betting that your data isn't being unserialized properly. Try writing a Serializer to inspect your inbound data more closely. http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.RESTSerializer.html#method_normalize

Comment: @JamieChong Yes, uacs contain values and I use them to render a select element

Comment: What does your template look like?

Comment: @JamieChong `<div class="dashboard black">
  {{x-woof}}
  <h1>{{t "uacs.header"}}</h1>

  <form {{action "save" on="submit"}}>
    <div>
      {{view "select" content=uacs
      optionLabelPath="content.title"
      optionValuePath="content.id"
      value=selected}}
      {{#if errors.selected}}
        {{#each error in errors.selected}}
          {{error.message}}
        {{/each}}
      {{/if}}
    </div>
    <div>
      <input type="submit" value="{{t "uacs.selectButton"}}">
    </div>
  </form>
</div>`

Answer (score 0):

This is intended to be a comment, but my reps not good enough. I guess since you've got this working when the value's a string this isn't any issue, but don't you need to define DS in upper case?

Comment: I thought about that, but I'm assuming the OP just made a mistake when typing the question here. He would have *much* bigger errors if `ds` was undefined.

Comment: Yeah, I agree, no idea otherwise! I'll delete this shortly!

Comment: I use requirejs and this code is inside of module. ds is equal to DS, but it is in local scope

Answer (score 0):

Just reading the docs here:
http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.html#method_attr

> By default, attributes are passed through as-is, however you can
>   specify an optional type to have the value automatically transformed.

So to me this implies that you shouldn't use `'number'` or `'string'` for your `selected` attribute.

```
DS.Model.extend({
    dummyFieldForErrors: DS.attr("string"),
    selected: DS.attr(),
    uacs: DS.hasMany("uac")
});
```

Comment: They are built-in types, I don't see any reason to not use them except the fact that number does not work properly in my case.

Comment: Hahah, I agree - was thinking out of the box :) This is what the NumberTransform code looks like: https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/1.0.0-beta.15/packages/ember-data/lib/transforms/number.js#L9 It should definitely be able to handle native integers. So it must be something else.